# Spring Security 4 JTwig put CSRF token in forms

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf, jtwig

How can i put CSRF token in form using JTwig?

I tried [this](https://github.com/jtwig/jtwig-spring-csrf-extension) extension but it doesn't work (showing error about {% **csrf** %} has no endblock). Also i tried putting HttpServletRequest object in model and then get token using [this](http://jmelo.lyncode.com/jtwig-and-springs-csrf/) snippet, but it had no effect at all.

Is there some generic way to implement csrf-token even without template engine?

Comment: The extension should just work. Can you leave here an example template that doesn't work?

Comment: Moved from JTwig to FreeMarker. No more sorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

I created a class called **ControllerSetup** (or you can name it anything you want) and I placed it inside the same folder as my Application class (the one with the `public static void main()` method). The code is as follows:

```
package some.pkg.of.myapp;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerSetup {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void initModel(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("_csrf", request.getAttribute("_csrf"));
    }

}
```

Now, any model in any of my controllers will automatically have an attribute called **_csrf**. I would use it in my JTwig forms as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="/some/action/url">
    <!-- My fields and buttons here -->

    <input type="hidden"
           name="{{ _csrf.parameterName }}" value="{{ _csrf.token }}" />
</form>
```